# Update existing composed model in Azure Form Recognizer

Tags: c#, azure, azure-form-recognizer

Is there a way to update existing composed model in Azure Form Recognizer.

So my problem is this`

I have fixed model id in the code , this model id is composed and builds from other models  , and I use it to get data from PDFs.

The model id is : read_pdf

So I get new PDF , I trained it , and now I want to marge this new one into  read_pdf composed  models,

How can I do this without changing the name read_pdf  but include new model into it?
Should I delete this read_pdf   composed one then again compose it from others models or how?